# SSS cause seams?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, subsurface-scattering

I've got a scene with a character's head and body is a different objects. Everything fit perfectly  BUT when I enable the SSS for the skin material I've got that seam between head and the body meshes. Please help me to get rid of it. I've searcher the whole web and found only 1 similar problem, but not the solution.

The Skin Shader is Generic Principled BSDF with SSS enabled. The subsurface is solid color

[image: Seam]